# Disable in-line autos when debugging in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

After a recent Visual Studio 2017 update (15.7.3??) the behaviour of the debugger has changed. When a breakpoint is reached all variables are displayed in-line as tooltips, causing a noticeable performance impact.

How to disable this?

As picture below -

[image: In line Autos]

Comment: I'm using 15.7.3 and I don't have this behavior. Judging by the wrong typeface used, I want to say this might be caused by a third-party extension instead of Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Yeah. Sure this is because of 15.7.3 and not some installed other thing that also updated?

Comment: If it's an add-in, ReSharper and CodeRush gives me the same info while debugging. (I use both of them in different environments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely ReSharper, and here is the [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/21/resharper-2017-3-brings-debugger-editor/). If you go **Options** > **Tools** > **Debugger** you can disable the option **Show local variables values in editor**.